# Finding a value in a data extension via REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I'm trying to find value based on the following logic:

Give me Subscriber Key where UserID = 12345. I would like to use REST API because after I have got the Subscriber Key I can use it to trigger an API Event in a journey.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
{
"request": {
    "attributes": [{
            "key": "BrightgenMasterAccountData.Subscriber Key"
            }]

},
"conditionSet": {
    "operator": "And",
    "conditionSets": [],
    "conditions": [{
        "attribute": {
            "key": "BrightgenMasterAccountData.UserID"
        },
        "operator": "Equals",
        "value": {
            "items": ["10615478"]
        }
    }]
}

}
```

And this is the response:

```
"resultMessages": [
    {
        "resultType": "Validation",
        "resultClass": "Error",
        "resultCode": "InvalidAttribute",
        "message": "There is no Attribute with FullyQualifiedName 'BrightgenMasterAccountData.Subscriber Key'."
    },
    {
        "resultType": "Validation",
        "resultClass": "Error",
        "resultCode": "InvalidAttribute",
        "message": "There is no Attribute with FullyQualifiedName 'BrightgenMasterAccountData.UserID'."
    }
],
```

I am using POST https://XXXXXXXX.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/search

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You’ll need to use SOAP to do that, there are no REST endpoints for retrieving data from a Data Extension: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_data_from_a_data_extension.htm

Comment: are you trying to retrieve this from external or within SFMC itself?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve this from an external system. The end goal is to combine this with another REST POST to trigger an API Event in a journey using the Subscriberkey I get from this REST POST.

Comment: Did you manage to fix the above with your REST Route? I'm currently running into exact the same issue. However the request works perfectly fine on the Contact object. I'm using this on a custom object like you as well.